# How is do loop working in this code ? Why call execute is working without loop ending?

Tags: sas

Need to understand why call execute is working when it is outside the loop for each iteration ?Variable name will be overwritten every time so I should get result for last variable in my dataset rather that all 111 variables.

```
data _null_; 
set basel.Data_Dictionary; 
do i =1 to 111 ;
call symput('Varname',NAME); 
%put &varname.; 
end;
call execute ('%missimp(&varname.)'); 
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by outside the loop?

The first thing that program will do is print the value that the macro variable VARNAME has BEFORE the data _null_ step starts to the log.  Note that macro code is processed first and then the resulting text is interpreted as the SAS code that you want to run.  It would be less confusing to place the `%put` statement before the `data` statement.

Your datastep will "loop" over each observation in your source dataset.  It will read an observation from your input data. The DO loop will cause it to set the macro variable VARNAME to the same value one hundred and eleven times. Then it will place a call to the macro named MISSIMP that will use the value of VARNAME (at the time the CALL EXECUTE statement ran). This will repeat until the SET statement tries to read past the end of input dataset. All of those macro calls will run after the current data step finishes.

A much simpler process would be just skip the CALL SYMPUT statement and use the value of NAME to generate the code to pass to CALL EXECUTE. Like this:

```
data _null_; 
  set basel.Data_Dictionary; 
  call execute(cats('%missimp(',NAME,')')); 
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification